# How to append multiple entries to JSON Array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

I am using `MySQL 8` and trying to update `JSON data type` in a `mysql table`

My `table t1` looks as below:

```
# id    group   names   
1100000 group1  [{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, {"name": "name2", "type": "user"}, {"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}]
```

The JSON format has two types - `user` and `dept`

Now, I have a list of users `userlist` as below:

```
SET @userlist = '["user4", "user5"]';
```

I want to append `@userlist` to the JSON Array:

```
UPDATE t1 SET names = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(names, '$', JSON_OBJECT('name', @userlist, 'type', 'user'))
WHERE `group` = 'group1';
```

The query is working but it is `incorrectly` adding data as below:

```
[{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, 
{"name": "name2", "type": "user"},
{"name": "["user4", "user5"]", "type": "user"}
{"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}]
```

`Desired Output:`

```
[{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, 
{"name": "name2", "type": "user"},
{"name": "user4", "type": "user"},
{"name": "user5", "type": "user"},
{"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE t1
JOIN ( SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('name', username, 'type', 'user')) userlist
       FROM JSON_TABLE (@userlist,
                        '$[*]' COLUMNS (username VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable ) jsontable
SET t1.names = JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(t1.names, jsontable.userlist)
WHERE t1.`group` = 'group1';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da25f6643c623d197a220931489864e2

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to ensure that duplicate users are not added to the same group?  For example, making sure that `user4` is not added twice @Akina

Comment: @meallhour If you need this then use JSON_MERGE_PATCH() simply

Comment: `JSON_MERGE_PATCH` is overwriting existing value. For example, if I add `user1` first and then add `user2` using `JSON_MERGE_PATCH`, in that case `user1` is overwritten with `user2`

Comment: @meallhour If you want to ignore new values for duplicated array elements then the only visible way is in parsing input array to separate values, check them individually for the presence preserving only not existent values, then combine them into the object and merge.

Comment: what will be the `select query` to check if any `user` element within `@userlist` is present inside `table t1`?

Comment: @meallhour See JSON_TABLE() function description, use it, then trivial join by JSON_SEACRH().

Comment: I have written following query to find entries where `name=user4`  but it is giving an error `Unknown column name`:   `SELECT t1.*
FROM t1, JSON_TABLE(users, "$.users[*].type" COLUMNS(f INT PATH '$')) as user
WHERE user.name = 'user3'`

Comment: JSON_TABLE must be used in FROM clause - this is the only MySQL function which produces the rowset. See Manual reference and examples in it carefully (you may also look at the same function in OracleDB).